# migrating accounts and keeping ids on import to relate to opportunities

Tags: opportunity, data-loader, account, data-import-wizard

I've been tasked with moving a small amount (under 5,000 records) of accounts, contacts, and opportunities.

I combined and cleaned everything in R/Excel.

I have imported all of the accounts and contacts using the data import wizard, and the contacts are related to the accounts, but i am unable to now import or relate the opportunities.

I'm using data loader as well and unable to connect them.

I keep getting **invalid cross reference id**, and after perusing the internet and this site, still can't find a way to import them, let alone import them and then relate them.

I believe this is because the accounts have new IDs, so I can't match them by ID either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a common issue with using the Data Import Wizard to do these types of migrations. 5,000 isn't _too_ bad, you can still attempt to update the Account references on the Opportunities using VLOOKUPs. But otherwise, you are left with either importing them using an External ID (not ideal if you don't already have one) or you can consider using a more specialized tool.

Comment: Realfire (https://www.datasert.com/products/realfire) supports loading child records while looking up parent id via a business key (need not be external id). See if that helps in this case. Disclaimer: I'm part of the team which makes Realfire.